# Difficult in aligning textview and ratingbar

Tags: android, xml, textview, alignment, ratingbar

I'm not so expert about XML and i need help to align two elements, a textview and a ratingbar.
I would to align the ratingbar (the five stars) at the same level of the textview ("user").
How to do this?

[image]

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/evento_pressione" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_button_pressed" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameMerchant"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Users list"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#f6911e"
            android:textStyle="bold" tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewName" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userM"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/userM"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:text="Comune"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4a4c4d"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rateM"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="@integer/five"
        android:stepSize="1.0" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="left" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="40dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameMerchant"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Users list"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#f6911e"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewName" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:text="Comune"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4a4c4d"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rateM"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userM"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you try with this one

Comment: Some thing changed, but not that alignment... what could be the problem?

Comment: i modified your code.for  allignment.. can you try it now

Comment: Doesn't work... can we speak in private so i can give my files?

Comment: send the required files to : kedar.kotkunde@gmail.com  i will check .. also which device you are using.. just for the reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/evento_pressione" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_button_pressed" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameMerchant"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Users list"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#f6911e"
            android:textStyle="bold" tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewName" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/userM"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/userM"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Comune"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#4a4c4d"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rateM"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="@integer/five"
        android:stepSize="1.0" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it puts the stars a the top and the textview and the arrow to the bottom :(

Answer (score 0):

I got excellent alignment using  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textRatingBar" on TextView along with android:paddingBottom="2dp" on RatingBar, (you may have to adjust values based on your font size)
[image]

here's excerpt from layout file:

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textDealTime"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Rating"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:numStars = "5"
            android:stepSize="0.1"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/main_teal"
            android:progressTint="@color/main_teal"
            android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/main_teal"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textRatingBar"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textRatingBar"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textRatingBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this might come in late but for those this might help in the future. Here's how I could achieve this.

The main attributes that need be applied to achieve it are

```
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/your_rating_bar_id"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/your_rating_bar_id"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

put this on your TextView element ensuring there's no constraint on it's height and it will vertically align it's center with that of the rating bar element with

id="your_rating_bar_id"

Hope this helps.